# Xcode build fails after changing build config in React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

I have been struggling to get schemes on iOS to work for my react native project reliably.

I followed the suggestions at https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5, as well as tried using [react-native-schemes-manager](https://github.com/Thinkmill/react-native-schemes-manager), which worked 1 time, but couldn't be duplicated onto another computer. I get all kinds of different problems, from libraries not found, to duplicate declarations and other problems. I have tried many many suggestions and none of them seem to work. I believe the problem all have to do with the build paths or search paths, but I am not expert enough in Xcode to figure out what is going wrong. I use quite a number of 3rd party libraries, including Code Push, Fabric, RNConfig, ImageCropPicker amongst others.

So finally I have decided to revert everything and start again from just the basic Debug and Release config, and have deleted all the additional configs and schemes. So, by doing this everything works (Run, and Archive).

Next, I just created a build config by duplicating the Release config, and called it Staging. Next I edited the working scheme release to use the Staging config for archiving, and ran the archive. This fails with the following message:

```
/opt/react/XXX/ios/XXX/AppDelegate.m:11:9: fatal error: 'CodePush/CodePush.h' file not found
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
```

Before I went through this exercise of deleting all the configs, if I used the previous Staging config in the same scheme, it this other error:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Ld Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XXX.build/Staging-iphoneos/XXX.build/Objects-normal/arm64/YYY.St normal arm64
    cd /opt/react/XXX/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Staging-iphoneos/QBImagePickerController -L/opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Staging-iphoneos/RSKImageCropper -L/opt/react/XXX/ios -F/opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/opt/react/XXX/ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/opt/react/XXX/ios/Pods/Fabric/iOS -filelist /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XXX.build/Staging-iphoneos/XXX.build/Objects-normal/arm64/YYY.St.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XXX.build/Staging-iphoneos/XXX.build/Objects-normal/arm64/YYY.St_lto.o -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/YYY.St.app/YYY.St -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lQBImagePickerController -lRSKImageCropper -lc++ -lz -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework Photos -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework CoreFoundation -lz /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libimageCropPicker.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTPdf.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNFetchBlob.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTVideo.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNVectorIcons.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTPushNotification.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNSound.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTAnimation.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTActionSheet.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTGeolocation.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTImage.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTLinking.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTNetwork.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTSettings.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTText.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTVibration.a /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a -lRNAudio -lRCTCamera -lRNDeviceInfo -lCodePush -lLRDRCTSimpleToast -lRCTOrientation -lPods-XXX -lReactNativeConfig -lRNPhotoView -lReact -lyoga -lcxxreact -ljschelpers -lRNSensitiveInfo -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XXX.build/Staging-iphoneos/XXX.build/Objects-normal/arm64/YYY.St_dependency_info.dat -o /opt/react/XXX/ios/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XXX.build/Staging-iphoneos/XXX.build/Objects-normal/arm64/YYY.St

ld: library not found for -lPods-XXX
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There are so many variations to the errors that I have had with this, so I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Have already set Header Search Paths, Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths to include $(BUILD_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)

I always clean project before trying another variation, but no luck...

Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think question has an answer here:
[Why does exact copy of Xcode Build Configuration fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471883/why-does-exact-copy-of-xcode-build-configuration-fail)

I wonder if this is caused by a bug in React Native - this looks similar to what you are reporting: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19929

If it is, maybe you can chip in and we'll get more attention towards this problem.