# xcodebuild fails when building with configurations but succeeds in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git-submodules, xcodebuild

I am trying to build different build configurations from the command line but whenever I am setting a specific build configuration it fails.

### Some notes:

- All builds are passing from Xcode
- Default configurations set for the command line is Debug
- I am NOT using cocoapods
- The project has submodules
- When adding new configurations, I added the same configurations to the submodules
- To fix the SEARCH_PATH, I added the settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471946/4697535
- IMPORTANT: When building with the default configurations, it PASSES

### Commands:

without configurations:

This is working and running the `Debug` configurations

```sh
xcodebuild -scheme <MyScheme> -sdk iphonesimulator.13.2
```

With configurations

```sh
xcodebuild -scheme <MyScheme> -sdk iphonesimulator.13.2 -configuration -Debug
```

```sh
xcodebuild -project <MyProject>.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator.13.2 -configuration -Debug
```

#### Error: No such module SomeFramework (this is a submodule)

The following build failed:

`PBXCp {some_framework_path}`

I tested with other build configurations and got the same error `[Stage, Debug, Release, Production]`. Don't understand why this would pass in Xcode but would keep failing in the command line. In addition, I don't understand why the default `xcodebuild` would pass with Debug, but when explicitly setting the `-configuration` to the same env, it will fail.

> Please note that there are similar questions but all face different issues, either using cocoapods or their xcodebuild script was wrong. I could not find any solution with build configurations and submodules

Comment: Have you tried with "Debug" instead of "-Debug"?

Comment: Thanks!!, I was breaking my head for hours. It was working for all config apart from Release. Any idea? 
Error: clang error linker command @madlymad

Comment: I think that linker error happens when, the library headers are there but the library code is missing. You have to check the xcode build flags for this library.